# Phase Change Computation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, phase-transition

I am wondering if the Navier-Stokes equations can predict the density jump (First Order phase transitions) within a liquid-vapor transitions? Or this discontinuity is only coming from the microscopic/molecular scale (determined by experiments).

Thanks

Comment: The Naiver-Stokes equations are mechanical force balance equations, not thermodynamic equations.  So they have nothing to do with phase transitions.  This is like asking whether the NS equation can predict the rate of a chemical reaction.

Comment: Well, i know that for chemical reactions, you have to add the source term into the continuity equation. But, by NS, im including the energy equation also. On transition, dP/dv = 0 so cp/cv will go to infinite then the temperature rate dT/dt will be zero (which is the real physical case for first order transition). Now, i dont know if there is a way to calculate the density jump through the NS mechanism (Instead of using the Clausius-Clapeyron equation for example). Thanks

Comment: In my judgment, the NS equations are not designed for this.  But, why, instead of wondering, don't you devise a few sample problems to model and see what the analyses lead to.  Modeling is a wonderful way of solidifying your understanding.

Comment: I am trying to model it. But, because of the fact that I remark a dT/dt = 0, that's why I was asking if the NS can get a possible link to phase transitions. Anyway, I will figure out how to get this. Thanks